# Adding Event Listener to an array

Tags: javascript

Im trying to do homework assignment and confused why I'm getting error message(undefined is not an object (evaluating 'buttons[i].style'))
any help appreciated Ive been trying to loop through the buttons array and add an Event Listener to each item in the list

```
var buttons = document.getElementsByClassName("quality");
for(var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i += 1){
buttons[i].addEventListener('click', function (i) {
    buttons[i].style.background = "red";
});
}



<!doctype html>

<html>
<head>
 <title>L.A. Hiking</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/hiking.css">
 </head>

<ul id = "navbar">
    <li><a href="index.html" class= "selected">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
    <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
</ul>
<body>

<div>
    <div class="blocks" id="selections">
        <ul id= "attr1">
            <li class="Instruction">Pick one:</li>
            <li class ="quality">Hard</li>
            <li class ="quality">Medium</li>
            <li class ="quality">Easy</li>
        </ul>

        <ul id = "attr2">
            <li class="Instruction">Pick one:</li>
            <li class ="quality">Hard</li>
            <li class ="quality">Medium</li>
            <li class ="quality">Easy</li>
        </ul>

        <ul id = "attr3">
            <li class="Instruction">Pick one:</li>
            <li class ="quality">Hard</li>
            <li class ="quality">Medium</li>
            <li class ="quality">Easy</li>
        </ul>
    </div>  
    <div class="blocks" id="results">
        <ul id = "choices">
            <li class="choice">Pick one:</li>
            <li class ="choice">Hard</li>
            <li class ="choice">Medium</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="button-container">
    <button>Go!</button>
</div>

<script src="javascript/hiking.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

The callback for `addEventListener` doesn't give you the index of the button clicked but an event object. You can then access the button using `event.target`:

```
for(var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i += 1){
    buttons[i].addEventListener('click', function (e) {
        e.target.style.background = "red";
    });
}
```

As per [@Sgnl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2612640/sgnl):

> since you are binding to the event to the object itself you could also
>   use context aka this so e.target.style.background = "red"; becomes
>   this.style.background = "red";

```
for(var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i += 1){
    buttons[i].addEventListener('click', function () {
        this.style.background = "red";
    });
}
```

Comment: Also, since you are binding to the event to the object itself you could also use context aka `this` so `e.target.style.background = "red";` becomes `this.style.background = "red";`

Comment: This PhD guy nailed it, he saved my bus seater array

Answer (score 0):

1. `document.getElementsByClassName("quality");` returns the collection of all the elements matching the class name *quality* in a `NodeList` object. From the code you posted, it seems that you are having the `listitem` and not the `button` element for the *quality* class name.
2. More importantly, the `addEventListener` callback would pass in the event information in the parameter to the callback. The property `event.target` returns the element on which the event was **registered**, which in this case is the `listItem[i]`. So, you need to use the `e.target` as `e.target.style.background = "red";`

```js
var listItems = document.getElementsByClassName("quality");
for(var i = 0; i < listItems.length; i += 1){
listItems[i].addEventListener('click', function (e) {
    e.target.style.background = "red";
});
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
 <title>L.A. Hiking</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/hiking.css">
 </head>

<ul id = "navbar">
    <li><a href="index.html" class= "selected">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
    <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
</ul>
<body>

<div>
    <div class="blocks" id="selections">
        <ul id= "attr1">
            <li class="Instruction">Pick one:</li>
            <li class ="quality">Hard</li>
            <li class ="quality">Medium</li>
            <li class ="quality">Easy</li>
        </ul>

        <ul id = "attr2">
            <li class="Instruction">Pick one:</li>
            <li class ="quality">Hard</li>
            <li class ="quality">Medium</li>
            <li class ="quality">Easy</li>
        </ul>

        <ul id = "attr3">
            <li class="Instruction">Pick one:</li>
            <li class ="quality">Hard</li>
            <li class ="quality">Medium</li>
            <li class ="quality">Easy</li>
        </ul>
    </div>  
    <div class="blocks" id="results">
        <ul id = "choices">
            <li class="choice">Pick one:</li>
            <li class ="choice">Hard</li>
            <li class ="choice">Medium</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="button-container">
    <button>Go!</button>
</div>

<script src="javascript/hiking.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Also, since you are binding to the event to the object itself you could also use context aka `this` so e.target.style.background = "red"; becomes this.style.background = "red";

Answer (score 0):

In addition to everyone suggesting attaching an event to each `li.quality` element, you could also consider this pattern.

You can attach one event to the parent element (instead of having an event listener for each `li.quality` element) by taking advantage of Event Bubbling ([see SO post here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4616694/what-is-event-bubbling-and-capturing)).

```js
let selectionsElement = document.querySelector('#selections');

selectionsElement.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  // stop event from bubbling further up the DOM tree
  event.stopPropagation();
  
  /*
    the `this` keyword will refer to the #selections element
    so we can't use it with this approach so we'll have to use `event`
  */
  
  // check if the element which triggered the event is li.quality
  if (event.target.classList.contains('quality')) {
    event.target.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
  }
});
```

```html
<html>
<head>
 <title>L.A. Hiking</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/hiking.css">
 </head>

<ul id = "navbar">
    <li><a href="index.html" class= "selected">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
    <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
</ul>
<body>

<div>
    <div class="blocks" id="selections">
        <ul id= "attr1">
            <li class="Instruction">Pick one:</li>
            <li class ="quality">Hard</li>
            <li class ="quality">Medium</li>
            <li class ="quality">Easy</li>
        </ul>

        <ul id = "attr2">
            <li class="Instruction">Pick one:</li>
            <li class ="quality">Hard</li>
            <li class ="quality">Medium</li>
            <li class ="quality">Easy</li>
        </ul>

        <ul id = "attr3">
            <li class="Instruction">Pick one:</li>
            <li class ="quality">Hard</li>
            <li class ="quality">Medium</li>
            <li class ="quality">Easy</li>
        </ul>
    </div>  
    <div class="blocks" id="results">
        <ul id = "choices">
            <li class="choice">Pick one:</li>
            <li class ="choice">Hard</li>
            <li class ="choice">Medium</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="button-container">
    <button>Go!</button>
</div>

<script src="javascript/hiking.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```